# Why is my redactor table converted to a text when saving?

Tags: craft3, redactor, richtext, table

I added the table plugin to my Redactor field. In the redactor field I can now include a table (see image below).

[image: Redactor table]

Upon saving the Redactor field, the table content is converted into text and put inside

tags (see image below).

[image: Rendered Redactor table]

This is what my settings for the Redactor field look like:

```
{
  "buttons": ["formatting", "link", "ul", "ol", "bold","html"],
  "formatting": ["h2", "h3", "h4"],
  "linkNewTab": true,
  "toolbarFixed": true,
  "pasteBlockTags" : ["h2", "h3", "h4", "p", "ul", "ol", "li", "br", "table", "td", "tr"],
  "imageResizable" : true,
  "plugins": ["table", "alignment"]
}
```

How do I make the Redactor field not strip those table tags and render the table correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

I was running HTML Purifier on my Redactor Fields and had to allow the table tags in my config/htmlpurifier/Default.json like this:

```
  "HTML.Allowed": "img[src], a[href][target], p, ul, ol, li, h2, h3, h4, strong, br, table, td, tr"
```